# Interstitial ads break after updating gradle / firebase, returns error ' Uncaught ReferenceError: videoInterstitial is not defined'

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, admob, interstitial

I had interstitial test ads working perfectly in the debug version of the app. So I put in my id for real ads (replacing test ad id). Worked perfectly, until I tried "release" version of the app. No ads showing.
So I added firebase and updated to latest gradle, now no ads are showing up at all. Also, Google Play store forced me to change target SDK version to 29+

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my app id goes here"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.31"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:29'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:29'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.4'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:19.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0'

    def lottieVersion = '3.4.1'
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:$lottieVersion"

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    dependencies {
        def billing_version = "3.0.0"
        implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:$billing_version"

    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why this is not working now? The app measurement is now enabled per firebase